# Magento add Gst Charge Before Shipping Charge In checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, totals

I create one extension to add GST charge,
and i want to add charge before shipping Charge

i add code in config.xml like

```
<cgst_charge>
       <class>gstcharge/sales_quote_address_total_cgstcharge</class>
       <after>nominal</after>
       <before>grand_total</before>
</cgst_charge>
```

but it not work for me it show like

http://prntscr.com/hirio0